# Selenium tests error: WebDriverError: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, protractor

I'm trying to run selenium tests but I get this error:

```
Error: WebDriverError: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=98.0.4758.80 (7f0488e8ba0d8e019187c6325a16c29d9b7f4989-refs/branch-heads/4758@{#972}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64)
...
From: Task: WebDriver.navigate().to(https://localhost:4200/asd)
```

I tried to update webdriver but still not working. I really know what to do because I'm really new to Protractor etc. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to send the browser to `https://localhost:4200/asd`. This is a URL that is passed to selenium. If you use Selenium Grid make sure that the URL can be reached from there. This especially means no `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` URLs, as they resolve to the selenium-grid-host.

If you need to detect the local network-IP you can try a variation of (node.js)

```js
    var address,
      ifaces = require("os").networkInterfaces();
    for (const dev in ifaces) {
      ifaces[dev].forEach((details) => {
        if (details.family === "IPv4" && details.internal === false) {
          address = details.address;
        }
      });
    }
```

and build the URLs with the detected address.